# Templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I've some problem with using templates:

myclass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

class myclass
{

private:


public:

    ~myclass();
     myclass();
    template<class S>
    void login(S login, S pass);
};



#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include "../additional_func.h" // for connect(QString,QString) function


myclass::myclass()
{

}

template <typename S>
void myclass::login(S login, S pass)
{

    additional_func->connect(login,pass);

}

myclass::~myclass()
{

}
```

in mainwindow.cpp (i'm using QT)

```
   myclass *vr = new vr();
   vr->login(ui->linelogin->text(),ui->linepwd->text()); // QString, QString
```

And I get error:

> mainwindow.cpp:31: error: undefined reference to `void ecore::connect(QString, QString)'

What way for using myclass::connect in other classes?

Comment: Where in the `#include` is class `ecore()` declared?

Comment: why is 'pass' shown in blue color? is it a C++ keyword or something?

Comment: @Chubsdad: It's a Python keyword.  SO's code syntax highlighting does a pretty good job of handling multiple languages, but it's not perfect.

Comment: It is a linking error. Provide the proper paths to your libraries while compiling.

Comment: @DumbCoder: Linker errors usually don't give you line numbers where the error occurred within your source code.  This is a compiler error.

Comment: You have `myclass`, `encode`, `login` and `start` mixed up in your code examples, or you are showing .h/.cpp files not related to each other. This makes your question hard to follow and difficult to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `login()` within `myclass` in your header, but you don't show us here that you've **defined** it anywhere.

Putting a semicolon after the function signature simply declares that this function exists.  It doesn't create a function.  You have to define the function in order to use it.

You can define it within your header, by putting the function body in `{}` instead of a semicolon.

```
class myclass{
    // ...

    template<class S>
    void login(S login, S pass){
        // code goes here
    }
}
```

Placing the definition here is one way to indicate to the compiler that you wish to inline the function, although the compiler may choose not to, anyway.

<strike>Or, you could define it within your .cpp file just like the other functions you've defined.</strike>

```
template<class S>
void myclass::login(S login, S pass){
    // code goes here
}
```

<sup>Because this is a template function that will (presumably) be shared by multiple code files, it has to be defined within the header.</sup>

Without one of these, there is no function body defined for the compiler to execute when you call this function, hence the "undefined reference" error.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the implementation of your template function in the header file, not in a .cpp file.

A template's definition needs to be available to the compiler when it should be instantiated. At the point where you call `vr->login(...)` the compiler needs to have the template's definition (the function body) available to create an instance `login<QString>()`. If the template function's body is "hidden" in some .cpp file then no function is created, and later the linker complains that it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

In the .cpp file, the method is named start(), not login().

Comment: start is a method of 'ecore' and not 'myclass' which should be fine isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, the whole thing is a bit confusing. Where is the definition of class encore?